# Count of cases where 4+ rows are saved for a record at the same time

Tags: mysql

I've got a table where data is saved for each user's record periodically rather than at the moment when it changes. Typically the max would be three rows saved at once for a particular user record, but sometimes the save doesn't happen till more have accumulated.  Trying to figure out how to count how many user records had a data save that was greater than three rows at once.

Sample data set:

```
+--------+---------------------+------+
| RECORD | SAVE TIME           | DATA |
+========+=====================+======+
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:19:09 | 1219 |
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:19:09 | 1133 |
| CARLA  | 2019-03-19 17:20:42 | 3785 |
| FRANK  | 2019-03-19 17:20:42 | 2335 |
| FRANK  | 2019-03-19 17:20:42 | 4451 |
| FRANK  | 2019-03-19 17:20:42 | 1126 |
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:22:05 | 5678 |
| CARLA  | 2019-03-19 17:22:54 | 4813 |
| CARLA  | 2019-03-19 17:22:54 | 7399 |
| CARLA  | 2019-03-19 17:22:54 | 3953 |
| CARLA  | 2019-03-19 17:22:54 | 7400 |
| CARLA  | 2019-03-19 17:22:54 | 1592 |
| FRANK  | 2019-03-19 17:23:27 | 1821 |
| FRANK  | 2019-03-19 17:23:27 | 3244 |
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:23:40 | 4912 |
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:23:40 | 2174 |
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:23:40 | 8421 |
| JOE    | 2019-03-19 17:23:40 | 3271 |
| FRANK  | 2019-03-19 17:25:25 | 5012 |
+--------+---------------------+------+
```

I'd like to get a count of "2" back from this data set, because CARLA's record had five rows added at `2019-03-19 17:22:54` and JOE's record had four rows added at `2019-03-19 17:23:40`.  (There were also four rows added at `2019-03-19 17:20:42`, but it was one for CARLA and three for FRANK so that wouldn't be counted.)

I did search for answers to this, but nothing quite matched what I'm up to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `group by record, savetime` with the condition `count(*) > 3` in the `HAVING` clause to get the rows you want and then count them:

```
select count(distinct t.record) counter from (
  select
    record, savetime
  from tablename
  group by record, savetime
  having count(*) > 3
) t
```

Comment: That counts how often a save for any record happens that's greater than 3 -- but not how many user records were impacted (so if 10 users had saves >3, but some users experienced it more than once, the result will be greater than 10).  Any idea how to get down to the count of impacted records?